# SDWebimage vs HanekeSwift's

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdwebimage, haneke

There are many caching libraries available in iOS. The most popular library is **SDWebImage** for caching images. There is one image cache library is **HanekeSwift’s** for image cache.

My question is **What is main difference between SDWebImage and HanekeSwift’s if both are working same?** In Which case we use SDWebImage or HanekeSwift’s?

Answer (score 6):

There are few difference between SDWebImage and Haneke. So it depends on user's choice with which Caching Library they want to go.

Here are few:-

***SDWebImage:-***

1) Categories for **UIImageView**, **UIButton**, **MKAnnotationView** adding web image and cache management

2) A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times

3) An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling

***Haneke:-***

1) Generic cache with out-of-the-box support for UIImage, **NSData**, **JSON** and **String**

2) Zero-config **UIImageView** and **UIButton** extensions to use the cache, optimized for **UITableView** and **UICollectionView** cell reuse

**SDWebImageCache:**

[image]

**Haneke:**

[image]

**Find various feature listing in below image to identify difference between all of them:-**

[image]

Hope it helps you to distinguish all of them

Comment: Seing point 2.
Do you mean that sdwebimage will store the original image and not the cropped one after resizing like haneke does?